# Drawing a ribbon on a <div> using images and CSS

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to make a ribbon with a div, :before and :after psuedo-elements and [3 pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Hwb.jpg). I got the :before image to work, but I can't seem to get the :after image to align to the right side. (please [don't link to css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/), they use pure CSS, I'm after images!)

I think using relative placements might be a better alternative to floats, but I don't quite understand them.

Aside: does anyone know what is causing the border around the bottom and sides of navbar-inner?

EDIT: Updated CSS because I hate when people post temporary websites on SO:

```
div.hero-unit {
    background: url(../img/ribbon-center.png) repeat-x;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    padding: 30px;
    float: left;
}

div.hero-container:before {
    content: url(../img/ribbon-fold-left.png);
    float: left;
    margin-left: -30px + -48px + 15px; /* - Padding size (30px) - image width (48px) + margin (15px) */
}


div.hero-container:after {
    content: url(../img/ribbon-fold-right.png);
    background: transparent;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -48px + -15px; /* - image-width (48px) - margin (15px) */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hero-container">
    <div class="hero-unit">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a negative right margin on `div.hero-container::after` .. I played around with it in Firebug and 15px seems about right. I'm not sure why the image isn't aligning to the right though.

`Aside: does anyone know what is causing the border around the bottom and sides of navbar-inner?`

Thats a box-shadow on `.navbar-inner` not a border

Comment: Thank you very much. I used :after instead of ::after, but I'm not quite sure why it works, [even after reading](http://bricss.net/post/10768584657/know-your-lingo-pseudo-class-vs-pseudo-element). And thanks for mentioning the box-shadow, that was driving me nuts and I just couldn't see it!